# React-dnd with multiple canDrops split via a array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I'm working with building a drag and drop from one div container to another. It works under a normal circumstance with the code below if I do not separate out my drop area into separate divs. However this is what I need to do so I hide the div's which are steps adn then use a next previous button to toggle through them however I can't create 4 separate dropzones because that number could change dynamically.

So my question is how can I split up the can drop section to make it dynamic based on the array its contained within. I'm mostly referring to the boxes.map area as that is what generates the result as you drag in any elements because I have it contained within another array but I need there to be Multiple CanDrops in this scenario there would be 4 because stepBlock is equal to 4 but I'm not sure how to tie that into the parent array. Here is my code:

```
 import { useDrag, useDrop, useDragLayer } from 'react-dnd'               
                
  let stepBlock = 4;

const ELEMENT = 'element';

const [{ isDragging }, drag, dragPreview] = useDrag(() => ({
    type: ELEMENT,
    collect: (monitor) => ({
    isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
    })
}))

const [{ canDrop, isOverCurrent }, drop] = useDrop({
    accept: 'element',
    canDrop: () => true,
    drop: item => {
    if (isOverCurrent) {
    setBoxes([...boxes, item]);
    }
    },
    collect: monitor => ({
    canDrop: monitor.canDrop(),
    isOverCurrent: monitor.isOver({ shallow: true })
    )
})

 <div className={'StepContainer'}>

  <div className={'stepControls'}>
      <div ref={dragPreview} style={{ opacity: isDragging ? 0.5 : 1}}>
           <div className='element' ref={drag}>
      </div>          
   </div>
 </div>

{[...Array(stepBlock)].map((e, i) =>
<div key={i} className={`stepBlock ${i !== index ? "hidden" : ""}`}>
    {boxes.map(member => (
        <div className="box">
        {member.name}
        </div>
    ))}
    <div className={`drop-area ${canDrop ? 'highlight': ''}`} ref={drop}>
    {canDrop ? 'Release to drop' : 'Drag a box here'}
    </div>
</div>
)}

</div>

<div className={'toggleBTNContainer'}>

<button
 disabled={index === 0}
 onClick={() => setIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex - 1)}
 className={'previousBTN'}>previous</button>
 <button
   disabled={index === stepBlock - 1}
    onClick={() => setIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1)}
     className={'nextBTN'}>next</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I haven't used react-dnd, but when I've built dynamic drag and drops I defined datasets for elements that are identified by 'onmouseup' or 'ontouchend' listeners. Reacts dynamic elements are normally produced from arrays( just as you do in your code) and as long as you know which entry, where you want to splice it in the new array and preserve the exact key of given element. You'll can efficiently rerender only the affected components and keep their states(given you utilize that correctly).. I have examples but they need some setup.

Comment: I see yeah any examples would be appreciated. I'm mostly trying to figure out how to split that inner array into separate arrays based on the parent array. because it wont work if its contained within the parent array.

Comment: Here's one I'm currently working on: https://github.com/whysosergious/tapz and here's a simpler version: https://github.com/whysosergious/tb and a concept demo for the latter https://www.zergski.com/demos/tb/ .. The former is a tad more advanced and requiers an apache server and Cors disabled, but the taskBoard should be enough for you to understand how this can be done.